# How to keep the double quotes at the end of a string when using tempfile in python

Tags: python, temporary-files

In the code below I have a string seperated by commas and the last value of the string is "". When I write this to the temp file using the code below the double quotes are dropped. How can I stop this from happening?

import tempfile
import os

fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()

with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmp:
tmp.write("abc,123,""")

Comment: The string `"abc,123,"""` is terminated at the first double-quote.  So Python interpreted this as two consecutive strings `"abc,123,"` and `""`.  Python automatically combines consecutive strings, so this turned into the single string `"abc,123,"`.

Answer (score -1):

To keep the double quotes you need to surround it with single quotes.

```
import tempfile import os

fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()

with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmp: 
    tmp.write('abc,123,""')
```